# How to improve speed on reading binary file in R

Tags: r, binary, data.table

I have to read in quite big binary files into R (to process, transform, convert to other formats). My approach, in general, works okay but, unfortunately, the script runs forever (>12h for the first part of the data which is less than 2% of all data).

I strongly assume that the problem is not genuinely due to the size of data (at least not as the only explanation) but due to inefficient code. I am looking for a way to speed up the runtime and am very grateful for any help!

My approach is mainly based on this tutorial: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-read-binary-data-into-r/

In the code below I only include two variables, instead of thousands. In total, the data is ~100GB, but as said above even processing the first part (<2%) takes >12h.

The data is already separated into smaller files which I process separately (for every part one script and one dataset).

My code:

```
newdata = file(paste0(getwd(), "/file.dat"), "rb")

# here, only first two variables
dataset <- data.table(ID = integer(),
                  v1 = integer())

# 327639 is the number of cases (data on people)
for(i in 1:327639) {
  bla <- readBin(con = newdata, integer(), size = 2, n=2000, endian = "big")
  ID <- i
  v1 = bla[1]

  dataset <- rbind(dataset, list(ID, v1))
}
save(dataset, file = paste0(getwd(), "/Output/", "Part_a.RData"))
close(newdata)
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: `rbind` is time consuming. Try to create your dt with `ID = integer(327639)` and then set the read in elements using indexing on the dt. Another idea would be to read chunks of data from the file, say 32Kb at a time, then a final read operation for the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is completely wrong, if so please excuse the noise.
My idea in the comment could be implemented as follows. (Untested, no data file.)

```
#numbytes <- file.size(newdata)
numbytes <- 327639L

dataset <- data.table(ID = integer(numbytes),
                  v1 = integer(numbytes))

chunk <- 2^15
passes <- numbytes %/% chunk
remainder <- numbytes %% chunk

i <- 1L
for(j in seq_len(passes)){
    bla <- readBin(con = newdata, integer(), n = chunk, size = 2, endian = "big")
    dataset$ID[i:(i + chunk - 1L)] <- i:(i + chunk - 1L)
    dataset$vl[i:(i + chunk - 1L)] <- bla
    i <- i + chunk
}
bla <- readBin(con = newdata, integer(), n = remainder, size = 2, endian = "big")
dataset$ID[i:numbytes] <- i:numbytes
dataset$vl[i:numbytes] <- bla
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Rui! That looks promising. I will definitely give it a try in a couple of hours, i.e. when the script finishes its current run (don't want to waste the last few hours by canceling now). I will then post/comment on the results.

Comment: @ThomasE I had made an error in the first `readBin`, change to `n = chunk`. (I've already edited the code.)

Comment: Hey Rui, unfortunately that approach doesn't work (or I cannot figure out, how). Your approach would work if the dataset was structured like in the above mentioned tutorial, first all bytes of var1, then all bytes of var2 and so on but my data is structured differently: first all bytes of person 1, then all bytes of person 2, etc. That's also the reason why I used rbind, instead of cbind (as in the tutorial). Do you maybe have any other idea?Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @ThomasE OK, I will edit my answer now that I have more information on the data structure, give me some time to think about it.